# JavaScript seems to be running "onscroll" event on mobile when one isn't present

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

My HTML is similar to this:

```
<span id="someDIV"></div>
<div id="anotherDIV"></div>
```

My JavaScript is similar to this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.toString();
var w;
w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

function someFunction(a, r) {
"use strict";
var someScript = document.createElement("script");
someScript.type = "text/javascript"; someScript.async = true;
someScript.src = "some script src";
document.getElementById("someDIV").parentNode.insertBefore(someScript, document.getElementById("someDIV").nextSibling);
}

function resizeUI() {
"use strict";
if (path !== "/" && path.indexOf("/category/") === -1 && path.indexOf("/label/") === -1 && path.indexOf("/default.aspx") === -1) {
    if (w >= 1305) {
        new someFunction(8, 2);
}}}

(resizeUI)();

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
"use strict";
w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
resizeUI();
});
```

Essentially what the `someFunction` does is load another script that performs an `innerHTML` that puts content inside of `anotherDIV`. It puts this script inside of the `someDIV` span. This script that gets loaded is coded similar to this:

```
(function() {document.getElementById('anotherDIV').innerHTML = 'something';})();
```

All of this code works as expected on desktop and mostly does on mobile as well. My problem comes when I scroll on mobile browsers. This causes the code to repeat and `anotherDIV` will get another `innerHTML` performed and the content will change. I know that this happens on Safari on iOS 10.

This problem makes it so that the original content that is loaded in `anotherDIV` are not able to be interacted with since it changes nearly every time you scroll through the page and stop; however, there is no `onScroll` event listener. My JavaScript is located in an external script file loaded before the closing `body` tag, which is why I don't use any `onLoad` events.

Comment: Safari's concept of window.innerWidth differs from the rest of the browsers. Have you tried using screen.width?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't resolve the issue. It happens on Firefox as well as Chrome on iOS.

Comment: Then it must be an IOS issue, maybe this page helps you with the issue: http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Comment: My friend pointed out to me that he has the issues on Android with Google Chrome, so I don't think it is an iOS issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to check the original screen size with the new size since scrolling was causing my `resize` event listener to fire. I did this like:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
"use strict";
var newWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
if (newWidth !== width) {width = newWidth; resizeUI(newWidth);}
});
```

I also added a parameter on the resizeUI function for those wondering about the argument passed in the above code. It seems when using my original HTML/CSS on my website, which had elements I didn't think were causing problems, a `resize` event was being fired. I haven't pinpointed the exact cause further than that.